# Issue mapping an array from api fetch call

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary

I reviewed previous posts and did not see anything that addresses this issue.  I'm using a functional component/hook to fetch data from an open source api. The code works as long as I am only displaying 1 field from data.map in the return render. If I try to display more than one, I get the following error: **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, catchPhrase,bs}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.** DevTools says the error is in the list component. When all but one list element is commented out, I can see that the entire array is returned in DevTools, and the one list element will display. Adding an additional fields(list items) results in the error.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function PeopleData() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

      function GetData(){
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => setData(response))

      }
      console.log(data) 

      useEffect(() => {
        GetData();
      }, []);
      
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(item => <div key={item.id}>
        <div>
          <li>{item.name}</li>
          {/* <li>{item.company}</li>
          <li>{item.phone}</li>
          <li>{item.email}</li> */}
        </div>
      </div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
export default PeopleData;
```

Comment: `item.company` is an object

Comment: @Ron Please vote up any answers you find useful

Answer (score 0):

Each object has the shape shown bellow, and the app is crashing because you are trying to render `company` which is an object, when it is expecting a string or node. So you should use `item.company.name` instead

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Leanne Graham",
  ...
  company: {
    name: "Romaguera-Crona",
    catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    bs: "harness real-time e-markets",
  },
};
```

You can also take advantage of the await/async syntax instead of chaining together then statements like bellow. The execution of the line is promised before the beginning of the next line by means of the await operator

```js
 async function GetData() {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json);
  }
```

I have this working in a sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-butterfly-dt2yy?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to display `company` property from the response.

From the API:

```
"company": {
  "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
  "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
  "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
}
```

This means that you have to display `company.name`, `company.bs` or `company.catchPhrase`.

Answer (score 0):

The company property is an object and an object can't be a child in React as it says in the error as well.

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name,
> catchPhrase,bs})

The solution is to only show properties from the company object that you may be interested to show in the UI.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function PeopleData() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

      function GetData(){
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => setData(response))

      }
      console.log(data) 

      useEffect(() => {
        GetData();
      }, []);
      
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(item => <div key={item.id}>
        <div>
          <li>{`Name: ${item.name}`}</li>
          <li>{`Company: ${item.company.name}`}</li>
          <li>{`Phone: ${item.phone}`}</li>
          <li>{`Email: ${item.email}`}</li>
        </div>
      </div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
export default PeopleData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Item.company is an Object, that's why React throws an Error. You have to access the attributes of company. If you want to display all attributes of Company you could built a "For In" loop and and display them all too. I can show you an example if you need clarification.

As a little side note and tip, look into the useFetch hook. You will love it, especially if you have multiple components that fetch data like this.